# laravel 4 - understanding model and database tables relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am learning laravel and I have following questions:

1. Is it required to have exact match of database tables with models? For example: can I have this scenario:   in DB: table1, table2, table3 but in laravel model i have groupOfTables.php, where groupOfTables represent all the 3 tables in the database.
2. All the 3 tables in my database are related. What query I can use on groupOfTables to retrieve records from all three tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend having a model associated with multiple tables. This is a misunderstanding of the use of Eloquent ORM.

If the tables in your database are related, the relationships can be described in the model methods. Here is an example using 3 models that are related. Car, Manufacturer and Parts.

**Tables**

- cars
- manufacturers
- parts

**Models**

- Car
- Manufacturer
- Part

---

Here is an example of your `Car` model. A car only has one manufacturer but many parts. We are telling Laravel this with these methods.

```
class Car extends Eloquent {

  public function manufacturer() {
    $this->belongsTo('Manufacturer');
  }

  public function parts() {
    $this->hasMany('Part');
  }

}
```

To query all the parts that belong to a car we could do this:

```
Car::find(1)->parts();
```

This is finding the `Car` with an `id` of `1` and returning all the parts that belong to it. The sequel query would be doing something similar to this:

```
select * from car where id = 1
select * from parts where user_id = 1
```

---

Here is an example of the manufacturer and parts now. In the logic below we are saying 'A part belongs to only one car, while a Manufacturer has many cars'.

```
class Part extends Eloquent {

  public function car()
  {
    $this->belongsTo('Car');
  }

}

class Manufacturer extends Eloquent {

  public function cars()
  {
    $this->hadMany('Car');
  }

}
```

We can then use this like this:

```
Manufacture::find(1)->cars(); // what cars does a manufacturer with an id of 1 own
Part::find(3)->car(); // what car owns the part with an id of 3
```

---

I know this does not directly answer your question, but hopefully this clarifies how to use Model relationships properly.

Comment: Thanks Ross Edman for the detailed explanation!

I have another question related to $fillable in my model:
  
lets say i have $fillable = { car_id, manufacturer_name, parts_name)  where car_id is in car table, manufacturer_name in manufacturer and parts_name in parts table.

so when I do: Car::find(1)->parts();

will the other fields (from manufacturere and parts table) of $fillable will be populated too?